# Stripe - Web Hooks - Change Subscription Plan After Free Trial

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to do the following:

- One Time Charge of 1£ which lasts 90 days
- After Trial Ends - Add User to new plan
- Charge user again when added to new plan

I understand that I will need to use web hooks for this and have created a test web hook to do this, which currently looks like this:

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_......");

// Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
$input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$event_json = json_decode($input);

// Do something with $event_json

http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater
```

The event that I need to listen to is:

> customer.subscription.trial_will_end

But how do I use this event in the web hook to get the customers ID and then add them to the plan whilst charging them at at the same time?

Kind Regards,
Nic

Comment: Dont you have to call some sort of API function to make Stripe return a result. Just setting the ApiKey probbaly wont do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you want to do, you might not need to use webhooks at all.

If you want to charge a $1 setup fee when a customer subscribes, then not charge them anything for 3 months, then start charging them $x / month (or any other interval), here's what you should do:

- [create an invoice item](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem) for the $1 setup fee
- then [create the subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) to the payment plan, with a trial period of three months (using the [`trial_end`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription-trial_end) parameter)

This will result in the following:

- the customer will immediately be billed $1
- if this payment fails, then the subscription will not be created
- if it succeeds, the subscription will be created
- 3 months later, the trial period will end and your customer will start getting billed according to the plan's parameters

To answer your initial question, the [`customer.subscription.trial_will_end`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-customer.subscription.trial_will_end) event that is sent will include a [subscription object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscription_object) in its [`data.object`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_object-data-object) attribute. You can then use this subscription object to retrieve the customer ID by looking at the [`customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscription_object-customer) attribute.

The code would look something like this:

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_...");

// Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
$input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$event_json = json_decode($input);

// Verify the event by fetching it from Stripe
$event = \Stripe\Event::retrieve($event_json->id);

// Do something with $event
if ($event->type == "customer.subscription.trial_will_end") {
  $subscription = $event->data->object;
  $customer_id = $subscription->customer;
}

http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater
```

Comment: I was just typing something along these lines when your answer came in. This is the solution I have used.

Comment: The workaround without Web Hooks is exactly what I am looking for and is pretty straight forward. Thanks a lot for the answer/suggestion!

Comment: Is there a way to create a plan and a customer at the same time? Looking at the API, I can see that they already have the customer ID, whereas im creating the customer on payment?